# Give read/write permission to FTP in linux server,(Client Windows)

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, readwrite

- How to give read/write permission to
  FTP (vsftpd) in linux (RHEL 5) server
  ( Client Windows ) ?
- How can i do if i want to give write
  permission for specific folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ftp server is set to use user accounts that are already on the server they will inherit file permissions. So if a user can cd and open a file via the cli they will be able to do the same in the ftp client.